# how to deploy crystal report 32bit on 64bit server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have an asp.net web application developed in VS2010 which uses crystal report 13 (32bit) to generate report. on local machine, the reports works fine, but on the hosting server, the CrystalReportViewer does not appear, and there are no error message. I later learned that Crystal Reports Runtime for Visual Studio 2010 (x64) is installed on the server.

I have searched google and sap websites but no solution. my question is: is there a ways to get crystal report 32bit work on 64bit server? and how can I do that? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve my own problem.
For those who may be facing the problem, please check this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/vscrystalreports/thread/ef56f72b-7ede-47d8-ba9e-9e63b9ac0203.)